# Saying Shema without tzitzit considered שֶׁקֶר?

Tags: tzitzis, shema

Struggling to understand the logic of [Shulchan Aruch Harav: Chapter 8:1](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3269356/jewish/Shulchan-Aruch-Chapter-8-Laws-Relating-to-Tzitzis-and-Enwrapping-Oneself-in-a-Tallis.htm#v1)

> "Whoever recites Shema without wearing tzitzit is giving false testimony." (כָּל הַקּוֹרֵא "קְרִיאַת שְׁמַע" בְּלֹא צִיצִית – מֵעִיד עֵדוּת שֶׁקֶר )

- How is saying Shema without wearing tzitzit even considered a Sheqer?
- Tzitzit simply serve as a reminder of כָּל־מִצְוֹ֣ת declared in [Bamidbar 15:39](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.15.39?lang=bi&aliyot=0), correct?

Comment: See Berakhot 14b

Comment: @חידה, did you see the note there: For the third passage of Shema spells out the obligation to wear tzitzis. However, unlike tefillin, tzitzis are not an obligation incumbent on one’s person: if one is not wearing a tallis he is exempt from the mitzvah of tzitzis (see sec. 17:3, 24:1, and 66:3).

Indeed, a marginal note in the Hebrew original suggests that the above statement about false testimony perhaps applies only when one is wearing a garment that requires tzitzis.

Comment: The hebrew note with the original sources: מ"א סי' כד ס"ק ג. זהר פ' שלח קעה, א. וראה גם לקמן רס"י כה לענין תפילין. ועי' לקמן סי' סו ס"ג וסי"א. סי' נח סוף ס"ד. וראה מה שדנו בזה בס' יד שאול. באר יעקב סי' כד סק"ד. מחנה יוסף (ציצית) ע' פא. פד. קטו. יגדי"ת (נ.י.) ל ע' רצו. עא ע' רכח. קובץ ד"ת (כפ"ח) חוב' ב־ג. אהלי שם ח ע' רכו. קובץ העו"ב תשעב ע' 60. תשעג ע' 50. תשעד ע' 61. תשעה ע' 86.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Shulchan Aruch Harav does *not* say you are lying about wearing tzitzit as other @Mordechai commented.

Rather he writes it is

> since everyone should be conscientious and eager to perform the mitzvos as soon as possible

This seems to be a transgression of the [second verse](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.6.5) of Sh'ma of loving Hashem since you are not doing an easy mitzva (see [M'nahot 43b](https://www.sefaria.org/Menachot.43b.14)).

This would follow the logic of the [Sefer Haredim (68a)](https://www.sefaria.org/sheets/389790.18?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) that extends the idea of false testimony to saying Sh'ma without the proper concentration or while thinking about money.

> Anyone who recites the Shema without intent testifies falsely, for it is written in it: 'with all your heart.' The same rule for would apply to prayer. And if one's thoughts are occupied with worldly matters, he is lying - 'With all your money', since he is prioritizing his over serving his Creator.